# CSS fixed grid side padding disappears on grid-column

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

```
* {
  /* CSS Reset! */
  margin: 0;
  /* They cascade, so for them to be accessible in
  the sidebar div, you have to make them available for all */
  --SideBarButtonSide: 36px;
  --SideBarOffsetX: 16px;
  --SideBarOffsetY: 17px;
}

#SideBar {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(2*var(--SideBarOffsetY) + var(--SideBarButtonSide));
}

#SideBar #SideBarGrid {
  display: grid;
  --SideBarTextHeight: 45px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 250px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 40px 200px 20px var(--SideBarTextHeight) 20px 200px;
}

#SideBarGrid #BrandLogo {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;

  margin: auto;
}

#SideBarGrid #SideBarText {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;

  text-align: center;
  line-height: var(--SideBarTextHeight);
  font-size: 35px;
}

#SideBarGrid #SideBarLinks {
  /* 1 / 2 and 3 / 4 work just fine! but try 2 / 3! */
   grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 6 / 7;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Whiteclaws/live/vpbRXL

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc8pw.jpg

This problem is a bit hard to put into words, so please just have a look at the codepen for yourself...

The small codepen and imgur gallery describes the issues pretty well.... You can switch to position: relative and it'll work just fine! but that would defy the point of a sidebar...

Note: One more thing, it breaks at three elements, if i only put in two (brand logo and sidebar text, it works fine!!)

Note2: It breaks even without the links, for that matter, just having the SideBarLinks div inside breaks it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `grid-template-columns: 1fr 250px 1fr;` to `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 250px;`. That is what you want?